# Is there a C pre-processor macro for getting the list of function parameters?

Tags: c, parameters, c-preprocessor

I have a C function which delegates its arguments to another. I would like to avoid explicitly writing those parameters in the call site of the delegated function. Is there a way (by pre-processor macro I'd assume) to get the list of parameters (without their type specifiers)?

Example:

```
extern g(int x, float y, char *z);

void f(int x, float y, char *z)
{
    ...
    g(x, y, z);
}
```

So I would like to write f's implementation somewhat like this:

```
void f(int x, float y, char *z)
{
    ...
    g(__params_list__);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything working better than just passing them normally.

Comment: This actually isn't possible, because during preprocessing, the compiler has no sense of actual function structures. The only alternatives are to use variadic macros and `__VA_ARGS__`, or `stdarg`-related functions/macros.

Comment: Wouldn't be better if you used structure instead?

Comment: The function signature is not up to me. I'm overloading a function in a given shared library for which I don't have the source.

Comment: It is not precisely clear, what you are aiming for. strictly speaking, `#define __params_list__ x,y,z` does what you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the code can lose readibility by doing some preprocessor-hacking, and worst if the only reason is to save some typing.

If this is only "just-for-oneself" programming, then a simple solution was already pointed out in the comments by **Jakub**: use a simple macro as a brief manner of denoting the list of parameters.

```
  #define param_list   x, y, z
```

As an alternative, you can investigate how the extension *Constructing Calls* of GCC compiler works. It's something similar to what is requested in the question (although GCC documentation prevents against using this feature without care).

[Constructing Calls (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html#Constructing-Calls)

Comment: The GCC Constructing Calls feature seems like the closest thing to what I'm looking for and my usage is pretty simple so I guess it should work. I now need to figure out if this is available for gcc in the toolchain I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

No such thing. Generally the pre-processor works on different level than compiler and does not recognise function calls.

Comment: So is it possible to implement this as a compiler extension perhaps?

Comment: Possibly yes, but if it is worth it is another question.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a `static inline` wrapper function containing the "advice" call to `g` *relatively* easily. This takes away the problem of trying to work out what the arguments were from within `f`, because you have a new scope to play in and control of the argument names and order when you generate the new function.

So given the following definitions:

```
// Generate an argument struct and unpacking/wrapping function
#define GEN_WRAP(F, A) \
struct F##_args_box { ZIP(GEN_STRUCTFLDS_, F##_ARG_TYPES, GENSYMS) }; \
GEN_WRAP_(F, A, (ZIP(GEN_ARGCALL_, F##_ARG_TYPES, GENSYMS)))
#define GEN_WRAP_(F, A, ARGS) \
static inline void F##_WRAP(struct F##_args_box __args) { F(ID(REST ARGS)); A(ID(REST ARGS)); }

#define GENSYMS (_0, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9)
#define GEN_STRUCTFLDS_(T, N) T N;
#define GEN_ARGCALL_(T, N) , __args.N
#define GEN_FCALL_(V, N) .N = V,
#define PASS(...) ZIP(GEN_FCALL_, (__VA_ARGS__), GENSYMS)


// Generic metaprogramming tools (not directly related to the problem)
#define NARGS(...) NARGS_(__VA_ARGS__, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
#define NARGS_(_10, _9, _8, _7, _6, _5, _4, _3, _2, _1, N, ...) N

#define CAT(A, B) CAT_(A, B)
#define CAT_(A, B) A##B
#define ID(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define FIRST(A, ...) A
#define REST(A, ...) __VA_ARGS__

#define ZIP(F, L1, L2) CAT(ZIP_, ID(NARGS L1))(F, L1, L2)

#define ZIP_4(F, L1, L2) F(ID(FIRST L1), ID(FIRST L2)) ZIP_3(F, (ID(REST L1)), (ID(REST L2)))
#define ZIP_3(F, L1, L2) F(ID(FIRST L1), ID(FIRST L2)) ZIP_2(F, (ID(REST L1)), (ID(REST L2)))
#define ZIP_2(F, L1, L2) F(ID(FIRST L1), ID(FIRST L2)) ZIP_1(F, (ID(REST L1)), (ID(REST L2)))
#define ZIP_1(F, L1, L2) F(ID(FIRST L1), ID(FIRST L2))
#define ZIP_0(F, L1, L2)
```

(you'll probably want to expand the metaprogramming tools to handle many more arguments, and maybe have non-clashing names)

You could then use code like this at the site of the definition of `f`:

```
void f(int a, float b, char * c) { }   // f *must* be defined
void g(int a, float b, char * c) { }   // before the wrapper macro!

#define f_ARG_TYPES (int, float, char *)  // These three lines
GEN_WRAP(f, g)                            // generate the wrapper
#define f(...) f_WRAP((struct f_args_box){ PASS(__VA_ARGS__) })
```

How this works:

First it generates a struct containing fields matching the argument types to `f` and `g`, in order. Then it defines a `static inline` function that unpacks that struct, and passes the fields to `f` and `g`. Because we generated the struct, we know the names of the fields (they're taken from an ordered list, so this scales to different numbers of arguments) and thus know what to pass to `g` without ever needing to know the actual names of `f`'s parameters. The actual call to `f` in user code is replaced with a macro that builds the struct in-place to pass to the wrapper function; this is type-checked in-place by the `PASS` wrapper around its arguments (optional, but if you left this out and then put the arguments in the wrong order it could break; restores the safety of not using macros).

Because we generated a wrapper function, arguments are only evaluated once; because the function is tiny, and `static inline`, it should have no effect at all on performance because the intermediate struct is easy for the compiler to remove.

If you wanted to get too clever for your own good, you could find some way to use the same argument-type-list in the original definition of `f`, to reduce your duplication further. (This probably wouldn't help anything though.)

Comment: I have deleted my own answer an upvoted this one, this fly must be killed with a bazooka! :)